# run software without installation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, deployment

i am developing a sale point application in visual studio 2008, framework 3.5, with sql sever 2005. To run this application, framework 3.5 and sql server 2005 should be installed on client's computer.

my problem is, my client keeps my software on removable disk, and he want to use this software on any computer where he inserts his disk, without installing sql server 2005.

how to enable this application run without sql server 2005 installation

in my application all business logic are saved in stored procedures.

Comment: Can you rewrite your application to use [SQLite3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) instead?

Comment: there is lack of features in sql-lite, it doesn't support to sotred procedure and alter table command.

Answer (score 2):

Given the constraints you have reported, consider distributing your application inside a pre-made Windows installation running under [VMWare Player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmware_player) or [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualbox) virtualized instance.

This assumes you're willing to install VMWare Player or VirtualBox onto the host machines. You could include the installers with your disk to make that task easier.

There are downsides:

- another system to update with service packs, security fixes, and so forth
  (virtualized systems are systems too)
- another license from Microsoft
- requires more memory
- file transfers between systems are annoying

But it does allow you to use the tools you like (SQL Server 2005) without requiring them to be installed on the host computers.

Comment: thnxx for answer i will try it

Answer (score 1):

Use [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact)

It does not require an engine to be installed and is compatible with SQL Server so migration could be easy.

Comment: Is it possible to install .NET from a disk?

Comment: but sql server compact doesn't support to stored procedures, and xml, in my application all business logic are saved in storedprocedures

Comment: @HaiderAli - I understand, if the client is willing to do a .Net 3.5 install, apparently the app is dependent on that, he might not object to installing SQL Express. An extra issue is licences. SQL Server 2005 is NOT free, so installing it at various machines can be illegal.

Comment: humm, this are big issues also

Comment: @HaiderAli - Sounds a bit like the app is just not designed/intended for the requirements of the client.